# How pass arguments for ctags / projectile-regenate-tags?

Tags: projectile

With the package `projectile`, I use `projectile-regenate-tags`. At the name already says, it regenates the TAGS-table of the current project on the project root.

It works likke a charm. However, I noticed not all files are included, the files with `.inc`-extension. I would make it so.

A good command for this could be the following:

```
ctags -f TAGS -e -R --langmap=php:+.inc.foo.bar --list-maps=php
```

I would like that `projectile-regenate-tags` use these parameters. When looking up the source code of `projectile-regenate-tags`, I found the following:

```
(defun projectile-regenerate-tags ()
"Regenerate the project's [e|g]tags."
(interactive)
(if (boundp 'ggtags-mode)
    (progn
        (let* ((ggtags-project-root (projectile-project-root))
            (default-directory ggtags-project-root))
        (ggtags-ensure-project)
        (ggtags-update-tags t)))
    (let* ((project-root (projectile-project-root))
        (tags-exclude (projectile-tags-exclude-patterns))
        (default-directory project-root)
        (tags-file (expand-file-name projectile-tags-file-name))
        (command (format projectile-tags-command tags-file tags-exclude))
        shell-output exit-code)
    (with-temp-buffer
        (setq exit-code
            (call-process-shell-command command nil (current-buffer))
            shell-output (projectile-trim-string
                            (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))))
    (unless (zerop exit-code)
        (error shell-output))
    (visit-tags-table tags-file))))
```

Aha, then look up what `projectile-tags-command` consists of.

```
(defcustom projectile-tags-command "ctags -Re -f \"%s\" %s"
"The command Projectile's going to use to generate a TAGS file."
:group 'projectile
:type 'string)
```

So in my `init.el`, I setted the variable `projectile-tags-command` to the following:

```
(setq projectile-tags-command "ctags -Re -f \"%s\" %s --langmap=php:+.inc.foo.bar --list-maps=php")
```

Evaluated it, and calling `projectile-regenate-tags`, I still don't get any relevant files with the extension `.inc`.
I still don`t get any relevant files. So perhaps I'm wrong somehwere.

Any good suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want `--langmap=php:+.inc` and without the `--list-maps=php` argument. [That example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953773/324105) (which I've just updated for maximum clarity) was just to show the effect of the `--langmap` argument, and wouldn't actually *generate* a TAGS file.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, now I get it totally, sorry for any inconvenience.